# Sluggish performance on Oracle VM

Tags: release-loki, virtualbox

I recently installed Loki on VM to test it out, but to my surprise it is sluggish and choppy. 
I have enabled 3d acceleration and 128mb graphic, 10gb ram and 4 cores of i7 with 100% limit.

What could be the reason? How to fix it?

Comment: I'm running VirtualBox on a MacOS host and I have found Loki to be quite sluggish. I have configured 128MB video RAM, 4GB RAM, 3D acceleration, and 2 cores — the same setup as I use for my Freya guest. Freya runs very smoothly, but Loki is unacceptable. Given that Feroiso is giving his guest installation much more resources than I am, and he's experiencing the same sluggishness and choppy response I'd conclude that Loki needs more development.

Comment: 3D Acceleration requires guest additions for support, otherwise disable both 3D and 2D support.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling all video acceleration. Uncheck 3D acceleration. Do not check 2D acceleration. I did this and performance improved markedly. The problem seems to be graphics rendering.